# how to display image from database to image control in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

i want to retrieve image from database but this code did not display any thing.
image data type in database is image.I dont know what is wrong with this code

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Write(Session["pro_ID"]);

    int id = Convert.ToInt32(Session["pro_id"]);
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data source=DESKTOP-QPTTS3M;initial catalog=shopolic;integrated security=True;");

    conn.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("spgetimage", conn);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    SqlParameter param = new SqlParameter() { ParameterName = "@id", Value = Session["pro_id"] };
    cmd.Parameters.Add(param);
    //cmd.ExecuteScalar();
    SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand("select  *from product where product_ID='" + Session["pro_id"] + "'", conn);
    //  cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
    SqlDataReader dr = cmd2.ExecuteReader();
    if (dr.Read())
    {
        name.Text = dr["name"].ToString();
        byte[] img = (byte[])(dr["image"]);
        if (img == null)
        {
            Image1.ImageUrl = "~/Images/bg.png";

        }
        else
        {
            string base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(img);
            Image1.ImageUrl = String.Format("data:image/jpg;base64,{0}", base64String);
            //     MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(img);
        }
    }
    //  byte[] bytes = (byte[])cmd.ExecuteScalar();
    // string strbase64 = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);
    //Image1.ImageUrl = "data:Image/png;base64,"+strbase64;
    //SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    //DataTable DT = new DataTable();
    conn.Close();
}
```

Comment: The code is working fine. I'm getting an image. Are you sure you are getting a result from the database and that the byte array is an actual (or not corrupted) image? Did you debug and check the value of `Session["pro_id"]`?

Comment: yes i have print Session["pro_ID"] value in a label and it print a correct 
id.

Comment: conn.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("spgetimage", conn);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            SqlParameter param = new SqlParameter() { 
            ParameterName="@id",Value=Request.QueryString["id"]};
            cmd.Parameters.Add(param);
            byte[] bytes = (byte[])cmd.ExecuteScalar();
            string strbase64 = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);
            Image1.ImageUrl = "data:Image/jpg;base64,"+strbase64;
              conn.Close();

Comment: this code also show null image

Comment: I also notice that you're not closing the reader...